# Which files to add in CMake build scripts?

Tags: c, cmake, build, compilation

This is maybe a simple question. Let's give one example of .c program:

```
   #include <stdio.h> 
   #include "Example.h"

   int main(){
   
   int x;
   return 0;
 }
```

If I have some C code which includes some .h file, i.e "Example.h" and in that header file are declared some functions which are implemented in i.e. "Example.c". Now I want to build this example using CMake files. Do I need to include also "Example.c" file ("besides Example.h") in the build process(CMake file)?

Comment: "Do I need to include also "Example.c" file ("besides Example.h") in the build process(CMake file)?" - Not sure what do you ask. If you want to build an executable, and `Example.c` defines `main` function for that executable, then obviously you need to include this file to `CMakeLists.txt`. Have you read a CMake tutorials (any of them)? Creating an executable is described by every tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CMake you would have to define your source files for the executable you wish to create, and yes that would include `Example.h` and `Example.c`. For example:

```
add_executable(myprogram Example.c Example.h)
```

or something on the lines of:

```
set(SRCS "Example.c" "Example.h")
add_executable(myprogram ${SRCS})
```

The following link provides a good introduction to CMake:

https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/basics.html

Although:

> CMake is smart, and will only compile source file extensions. The headers will be, for most intents and purposes, ignored; the only reason to list them is to get them to show up in IDEs.

Comment: I thought so, thank you for the answer :)

Comment: And if i.e "Example.h" includes some "Example1.h" I need to add also "Example1.h" in CMake script?

Comment: @miki1307 Not necessarily, `add_executable(myprogram ...)` will create the target `myprogram` and compile the given `c` files. Using `target_include_directories(myprogam ${MY_DIR})` will allow the executable to find the header files that you need, so as long as they are included you should be able to build your executable if `MY_DIR` is set to the directory of your header files. And then additionally when you want external libraries you can use `target_link_libraries(myprogram other_lib)`